# does this (existe element ) function work properly using recursion

Tags: c, linked-list

i created a function to detect if a word does exist in a linked list with recursion.

i wanted to know if its correct or not .

---

```
bool does_exist_in_list(index *head,char word[25]){

    while( head != NULL ){
       //to detect the first element 
       if(strcmp(word,head->word) == 0)
           return true;

       else{ 
       //to go to the next element
           return does_exist_in_list(head->next,word);
           }
    }

}
```

---

because im using it in a long code so i dont know if there is a problem in it

Comment: Try changing `while()` to `if()`... (PS: using `else` is unnecessary after an `if()` codeblock that ends with `return`... Think about the flow; execution (the program counter) has gone elsewhere already...)

Comment: I dont think something is wrong

`
bool does_exist_in_list(index *head,char word[25]){
    if(head!=NULL){
         if(strcmp(word,head->word) == 0)
           return true;
    }      
    return does_exist_in_list(head->next,word);
}
`
try using these changes
and let me know if it works

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar sorry i didn't reply faster , but yeah ur code works too !! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop is misleading, as the function always returns during the first iteration.

Additionally, if `head` is NULL, the function fails to return a value at all, invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

```
bool does_exist_in_list(index *head, char word[25])
{
    if (!head)
        return false;
    
    if (0 == strcmp(word, head->word))
        return true; 
    
    return does_exist_in_list(head->next, word);
}
```